# Referencing multiple shapes by name

Tags: excel, vba, reference, shapes

I'm trying to turn multiple shapes (just standard rectangles created by insert -> shapes) yellow when I click on a command button. I selected all the shapes and named them "rect" The name manager acknowledges that the name exists and it includes all the specified shapes. However, when I try to run this

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("rect").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

I get a runtime error "The item with the specified name wasn't found." The weird thing is that this works perfectly fine with just one shape, but when the name refers to multiple shapes then it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the shapes as needed and run the code below

```
Sub Carmello()
Selection.Group.Select
Selection.Name = "rect"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("rect").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code actually made me figure out what I was doing wrong. First I have to group all the shapes, and then name it.